# how to center the tabs in a spry tabbed panel?

Tags: spry

Is there a way to put the tabs of a spry tabbed panel in the center?

```
     +------+------+
     |Tab  1|Tab 2 |
     +------+------+
+-----------------------+
|         panel         |
|                       |
+-----------------------+
```

At the moment they are on the left by default.

Answer (score 0):

According to this example:
http://adobe.github.io/Spry/samples/tabbedpanels/tabbed_panel_sample.htm

```
<ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 1</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 2</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab TabbedPanelsTabSelected" tabindex="0">Tab 3</li>
    <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab 4</li>
</ul>
```

Just work on css, adding these rules to center the tabs menu (i tried on the fly with firebug):

```
.TabbedPanelsTabGroup{
    text-align: center;
}
.TabbedPanelsTab{
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```